# PHP - Parsing JSON

Tags: json

How can I parse JSON with the following format in PHP?

```
renderBasicSearchNarrative([{"place_id":"118884","lat":"41.5514024","lon":"-8.4230533"},{"place_id":"98179280"..........}])
```

I want to get the lat, lon that appears in first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `json_decode` function for this. It will return an object similar to below and you can access it by key. Hope that's what you're looking for!

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [place_id] => 118884
            [lat] => 41.5514024
            [lon] => -8.4230533
        )

)
```